# Display one time message to user upon logging in

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm looking for a module (or another way) of displaying a message to all users only once after they login. Basically, a client wants to add a newsletter on their site, and would like to give the change to all the users with accounts once they login to signup to the newsletter. They just want the message to appear once, the user can dismiss it, and then it will never display again. Ideally it would be possible to generate more messages at future dates for other reasons (changes to privacy policy, offers, etc).

I've looked at a few modules, including [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag), [Absolute Messages](http://drupal.org/project/absolute_messages) and [EU Cookie Compliance](http://drupal.org/project/eu-cookie-compliance) but none seem to do what I need.

Anyone know of a module or a method of implementing this with the above modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the [Splashify module](http://drupal.org/project/splashify)

> Display a splash page anywhere on your site by redirecting the user,
>   showing a lightbox, or displaying a popup. This module is designed to
>   be search engine friendly, mobile device friendly and offers multiple
>   configuration options.

Comment: Looks promising! will give it a go and get back to you!

Comment: Does the trick, but I just can't restrict it to only Authorized users! Any experience?

Comment: Sorry Mark, no experience with that

Comment: No worries, time to be bad and hack the module

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the Rules module installed?

You can try creating a rule with the following settings:

- Event:       User has logged in
- Elements:    User has role (set it to authenticated users)
- Actions:     Show a message on the site (set your welcome message here)

Drupal will show your welcome message as a system message. There you go!